# neo4j browser can not start database (version 1.3.5)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I'm using windows 10. Neo4j browser update to version `1.3.5`. After that I always get an error saying

> "Database failed to start: Database process terminated, see logs..
> Check the logs"

When I check the folder `logs` I see nothing. Please help

Comment: I had to deal with a similar problem. For me the solution was to start neo4j as admin.

Comment: I solved my issue. https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-desktop-1-3-5-can-not-start-database-on-windows-10/24760 Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the logs there `%USERPROFILE%.Neo4jDesktop\log.log` They say they can not read somewhere in AppData folder.

After I uninstalled and deleted some folder inside somewhere AppData\Local manually and then reinstalling Neo4j Desktop, it worked fine.

I deleted some folders inside somewhere AppData manually. I think, when I uninstall Neo4j Desktop and check to delete all the folders, it should have deleted them but it didn't.

It is very strange that when I check the newest version on the website I see 1.3.4. But somehow my neo4j desktop suggested 1.3.5 and installed it.